# Bugs in xgboost logistic regression?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, boosting

Here is a simple data simulation and a function that fits a logistic regression on the simulated data and returns the maximum of the fitted values:

```
library(xgboost)
# Simulate some gaussian predictors and binary outcomes data
set.seed(1)
x = sapply(1:10, function(k) rnorm(100))
y = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.5)
# Fit an xgboost regression and return the maximum fitted value
maximum_fitted_value = function(obj, n){
    params = list(seed = 1, objective = obj)
    bst = xgboost(data = x, label = y, params, nround = n, verbose = 0)
    fits = predict(bst, newdata = x)
    return(max(fits))
}
```

This makes it easy to demonstrate two deeply troubling problems:

1. `xgboost` thinks that logitraw values should be the same as logit values:

> ```
> > maximum_fitted_value(obj = "binary:logit", n = 2)
> [1] 0.7487798
> > maximum_fitted_value(obj = "binary:logitraw", n = 2)
> [1] 0.7487798
> ```

2. `xgboost` probabilities can exceed 1:

> ```
> > maximum_fitted_value(obj = "binary:logit", n = 50)
> [1] 1.000616
> ```

Is there an error in my code, or does this reveal real xgboost (or R interface) bugs?

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but this line of code is confusing to me: `    bst = xgboost(data = x, label = y, params, nround = n, verbose = 0)
`.  Why did you pass all the arguments as named arguments except the third, which was positional?  That's very confusing, and the kind of thing that is very liable to create bugs.

Comment: If you check the docs, the third positional argument is *not* params.  I'm not sure how this interacts with R's arcane argument binding rules, but I would explicitly pass in your params object as a named argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As @MatthewDrury pointed out, `params` should be a named argument or put in the right position.
2. The right objective is `binary:logistic`, not `binary.logit`:

> ```
> maximum_fitted_value2 <- function(obj, n) {
>   params <- list(seed = 1, objective = obj)
>   bst <- xgboost(data = x, label = y, params = params, nround = n, verbose = 0)
>   fits <- predict(bst, newdata = x)
>   return(max(fits))
> }
>
> maximum_fitted_value2(obj = "binary:logistic", n = 2)  # 0.6952068
> maximum_fitted_value2(obj = "binary:logistic", n = 50) # 0.9959001
> maximum_fitted_value2(obj = "binary:logitraw", n = 50) # 5.492696
> ```

Now, to make this question at least to have some statistical flavor: Due to the first or second problem mentioned above, `xgboost` uses the default `reg:linear` objective. This both explains predicted probabilities above 1 and the equality to `binary.logitraw`.

Edit: Ctrl+K not working for code highlighting?